# Why does macOS show 100% battery and fully charged when "Charge Remaining" is lower than "Full Charge Capacity"

Tags: battery, system-information, charge

My Battery percentage shows 100% Mark. But I got this from the **System Information** section. Why does it say **fully charged** and shows **100%** mark when the actual remaining charge is 95%? 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is completely normal.

The numbers you see here should not be treated exact values - it is impossible to get exact values for the battery. The full charge capacity varies slightly with various factors - including, for example, the ambient temperature in your room.

The battery will ofcourse report a specific number to the operating system, but it would be a bad idea to expect the numbers to match up exactly. I.e. if you just charged until "Charge Remaining" matched exactly with "Full Charge Capacity" that wouldn't be a good strategy. This is why you see that systems from all manufacturers charge to somewhere "near 100%" - for example 95%.

Comment: And as batteries age they no longer hold as much charge. So if your battery is at 95% charge but can only be charged to 83% of original capacity... well you get the point.

Comment: @SteveChambers That doesn't really come into play here... as the battery ages the "Full Charge Capacity" value is lowered - it doesn't stay at the initial value.

Comment: @lx07 You misunderstood me. I'm not saying that the computer can't display the exact value reported by the battery controller - that would be weird. I'm saying that it doesn't make sense to treat it as an exact value, as the "real value" fluctuates with - for example - temperature. That's why you do not want to go to 100%, but _on purpose_ go for 95% for example.